# How to add backend business logics when using firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, web, backend

If we access firebase **directly** from web-client ,

1. 1.Is it a must to have all the business logics in web-client it self? is there any way to **set backend logics at firebase**?
2. Is it **secure** to do all the logics in front end web-client (since any one can read the code)?
3. Can I have a comparison between, "**writing the firebase code in web-client it self**" and "**having a node server which communicates with firebase**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to keep business logic and any thing that needs to be secured in web client. If you are using only Firebase products and want to implement backend business logic in Firebase, you can use Firebase cloud functions. For examples, see [firebase cloud function examples](http://www.zoftino.com/android) in firebase section.

Comment: So you mean, I don't have to run a node server and use firebase for node, but instead I can write everything in the client side and set important business logics as cloud functions in firebase side?

Comment: yeah, that is correct. Something that is sensitive should into cloud functions and make sure you define security rules to protect cloud functions.